# How can I search for a specific function and then edit it?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

Unless I'm missing something, the App Script Editor lacks the ability to find a specific function within the project.

I'd like to be able to search for a specific function and then edit it.

Alternatively, how can I view a list of functions within my project (and which .gs file each is in)?

To be clear, I have a number of (logically named) .gs script files within my project each with a number of functions within.

Answer (score 1):

The new Monaco script editor lacks cross-file search, but the legacy script editor has this feature. So a workaround is to click `Use legacy editor` in the top right-hand corner and do your search there.

Click the star icon ☆ in the top left-hand corner of [issue 175233560](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175233560) to vote for this feature request and get notified of changes in status.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I clicked 'Use legacy editor' but still couldn't find this feature.  Did I miss something?

Comment: In the legacy editor, press `Control+F` to search. The search dialog box will show a list of files in the script project that contain a match, at the bottom of the dialog box. Click a file name to open that file and go to the first match.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet an available feature for the new Apps Script IDE - however there is already a fearure request for enabling cross-file search on Google's Issue Tracker:

- [Search function in Apps Script editor should allow searching of all project files, not just the currently open one.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175233560)

Google prioritises feature requests by popularity, so make sure to give the issue a star on the above page to let them know this is highly requested.

In the mean time, the legacy editor still has cross-file search available, so you can use this to search in all project files at once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does seem to lack that ability as far as I can see.  I use control f and then just select between the different files.  It keeps the search active between files. Making it possible to find strings in other files.  I would prefer if it would just tell me where but I haven't identified that ability as yet.